# Is there way to change default Haystack form template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to change the Django-haystack default form template.

default form template comes like

```
        <table>
        <tr><th><label for="id_q">Ara:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="q" id="id_q" /></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Ara">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

when i say `{{form}}` I dont want the label "Ara" and also some modifications in template. But I couldn't find where to remove it in folder site-packages/haystack.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the default form. The easiest way (which I tend to use) is just to define a plain html form pointing to your search url in a base template and then inherit from that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really more about form rendering than anything specific to Haystack.

What you want to do is use a custom form template for this specific form or choose a new general form template to use for rendering the form. This is where I'd point you in the direction of something like [Django-floppyforms](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for better form rendering. These packages, and [several others](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/forms/), provide some nicer default templates and more control over form rendering.